# Running TestNG test sequentially with time-gap

Tags: unit-testing, junit, dao, testng

I have couple of DAO unit test classes that I want to run together using TestNG, however TestNG tries to run them in parallel which results in some rollbacks failing. While I would like to run my Unit Test classes run sequentially, I also want to be able to specify a *minimum* time that TestNG must wait before it runs the next test. Is this achievable?

P.S. I understand that TestNG can be told to run all the tests in a test class in a SingleThread, I am able to specify the sequence of method calls anyway using groups, so that's not an issue perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

What about a [hard dependency](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) between the 2 tests? If you write that:

```
@Test
public void test1() { ... }

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "test1", alwaysRun = true)
public void test2() { ... }
```

then `test2` will always be run **after** `test1`.

Do not forget `alwaysRun = true`, otherwise if `test1` fails, `test2` will be skipped!

Comment: Hi Romaintaz, Thanks but as I mentioned the issue is not with the dependency between tests within a test class (I already have used dependsOnGroups for that), the issue is with running multiple Test Classes, one after another (as in a test suite).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you do not want to run your classes in parallel, you need to specify the parallel attribute of your suite as false.  By default, it's false.  So I would think that it should run sequentially by default, unless you have some change in the way you invoke your tests.
2. For adding a bit of delay between your classes, you can probably add your delay logic in a method annotated with @AfterClass.  AFAIK testng does not have a way to specify that in a testng xml or commandline.  There is a timeout attribute but that is more for timing out tests and is not probably what you are looking for.

For adding delay between your tests i.e. test tags in xml, then you can try implementing the ITestListener - onFinish method, wherein you can add your delay code.  It is run after every `<test>`.  If a delay is required after every testcase, then implement delay code in IInvokedMethodListener - AfterInvocation() which is run after every test method runs.  You would need to specify the listener when you invoke your suite then.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Following is what I used in some tests.

**First**, define utility methods like this:

```
// make thread sleep a while, so that reduce effect to subsequence operation if any shared resource,
private void delay(long milliseconds) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
}

private void delay() throws InterruptedException {
    delay(500);
}
```

**Then**, call the method inside testing methods, at end or beginning.

e.g

```
@Test
public void testCopyViaTransfer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    copyViaTransfer(new File(sourcePath), new File(targetPath));
    delay();
}
```